# How can I add a new line after every n characters

Tags: python

For example:

```py
words = '''Hey #Jaipur, I am Organising an event named "Clean Jaipur" Online. Please Make sure to mark 
your attendance. Date - 10 August 2023 via zoom'''
```

I want that when I print it, after every 5 words there is a new line.

```
def wrap_words(text: str, k: int = 2, *, sep: str = None) -> str:
    text = text.strip().split(sep)
    data = list(zip(*[iter(text)] * k)) + [words[-(len(text) % k):]]
    return "\n".join(" ".join(i) for i in data)


print(wrap_words(words, 5))
```

I tried this but it did not work.

Comment: Have you tried writing a simple loop? This code looks too complicated for me to understand what is wrong with it.

Comment: count the characters and then use modulo operator on the counter

Comment: Don't write so complex, maybe you can write so more simple it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to go to a new line when the current whole line is too long (not determined by number of words but by number of characters, since words can differ a lot in length)?

Answer (score 1):

This is code: (I explained with comments)

```py
def wrap_words(text: str, k: int = 2, *, sep: str = None) -> str:
    text = text.strip().split(sep)
    res = ""
    for index, item in enumerate(text):
        # add \n for every k items (it runs at first iteration too because 0%num is equal to 0 ever)
        if index % k == 0:
            res += '\n'
        # add every item to result
        res += item
    # remove first \n and return
    return res[1:]
```

Simply calculate the mod for finding every n characters and finally remove first char because `0 % n` is 0 everytime.

Comment: The loop should use `enumerate()` directly: `for index, element in enumerate(text):`. It gives you indices as well as the elements themselves.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace the return value with `"\n".join(" ".join(i) for i in data[:-1])` it prints it in every 5 words in line as you wish:

```
Hey #Jaipur, I am Organising
an event named "Clean Jaipur"
Online. Please Make sure to
mark your attendance. Date -
10 August 2023 via zoom
```

Answer (score 0):

what the hell are you doing for a simple problem? just split into words , add new line to every 5 words and join them back

```
words = '''Hey #Jaipur, I am Organising an event named "Clean Jaipur" Online. Please Make sure to mark 
your attendance. Date - 10 August 2023 via zoom'''

words=words.split()
i=0
while i<len(words):
    if (i+1)%5==0:
        words[i]=words[i]+'\n'
    i+=1
words=' '.join(words)
print(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

To use your original function:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest


def wrap_words(text: str, k: int = 2, *, sep: str = None) -> str:
  text = text.strip().split(sep)

  # The tuples returned by zip_longest will always have k elements,
  # with empty slots filled with None if necessary
  data = zip_longest(*[iter(text)] * k)
  
  # For each zipped tuple, join only non-None elements
  return "\n".join(" ".join(w for w in e if w) for e in data)
```

Try it:

```py
words = '''Hey #Jaipur, I am Organising an event named "Clean Jaipur" Online. Please Make sure to mark
your attendance. Date - 10 August 2023 via zoom foo bar'''

print(wrap_words(words, 5))

# Hey #Jaipur, I am Organising
# an event named "Clean Jaipur"
# Online. Please Make sure to
# mark your attendance. Date -
# 10 August 2023 via zoom
# foo bar
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like one-liners, here's one:

```
from itertools import cycle

def wrap_words(text: str) -> str:
    return ''.join(map(''.join, zip(text.split(), cycle([' '] * 4 + ['\n']))))
```

Example:

```
>>> print(wrap_words('A B C D E F G H I J K L'))
A B C D E
F G H I J
K L
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting a new line after a fixed number of words seems like a bad attempt to reach a certain line length. Words can have very different lengths. So I instead propose to do what your ***title*** asks for, namely *"add a new line after every n characters"*. Using Python's own [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html):

```py
import textwrap

words = '''Hey #Jaipur, I am Organising an event named "Clean Jaipur" Online. Please Make sure to mark your attendance. Date - 10 August 2023 via zoom'''

for line in textwrap.wrap(words, 30):
    print(line)
```

Output ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PY8xTgNBDEX7OcVXKDaRkmhJGoREgaAAJBSuYLHOZpSMZ-TxJCxXoUkDd6LkJuwSwIWLr6ev_94-UmebKMfje7H17OLzy4cU1WD8Ygel5NwhapNxhaqq7rjD2QP5VHSKe1DASlsSn720IAHvWQxCgRuMbnbcRyd6hJXsvPAcT32aGY-0ZeSiDIsIpFt0sSjIjKUhee7JWzLGDOc1rktbsmFRL5bYe8JrjKFf49w6KoZaePkfPB_e-Gf0FMt6cunQX1IvNh7YyUn01_fP-xs)):

```
Hey #Jaipur, I am Organising
an event named "Clean Jaipur"
Online. Please Make sure to
mark your attendance. Date -
10 August 2023 via zoom
```